# NumericProperty wont update

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to update the position of a widget via a NumericProperty. I have it updated in a function. When the function has been called the NumericProperty wont update

main.py

```
class Game(Screen):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    x_value = NumericProperty(x)
    y_value = NumericProperty(y)

    def update(self):
        self.x = self.x + 20
        self.y = self.y + 30
```

main.kv

```
Game:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "higher"
            pos: (root.x_value + root.y_value)
            on_release: root.update()
```

The Button stays at the same position. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your NumericProperty definitions are equivalent to `x_value = NumericProperty(0)`, they don't know anything about the fact that the argument passed to them was named x in the local namespace. It looks like you expect updating self.x later will affect the NumericProperty, but this is not the case.

You can instead directly write `self.x_value = self.x_value + 20` without reference to the initial-value variable. This should do what you want.

Comment: Does this need to be declared in the function? I have done it in the func and it still doesn't update.

Comment: I'm not sure if just changing the `pos` of your button will work either, as it's in a FloatLayout. I suggest asking a new question with a full minimal runnable example if you can't get it to work.

Comment: I have made a small runnable application, I hope that you might me able to help me further. I have been trying to solve this for the past 3 days, your help would mean a ton. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71739615/updating-numericproperty