# Updating NumericProperty

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to update the position of a widget via a NumericProperty. When the function has been called the NumericProperty wont update. Updating inside of the function does not update the `pos` of my widget; updating outside yields an error. What can I do?

This code has been simplified

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import mainthread
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, BooleanProperty

class Game(App):
    X_value = 0
    X_value = 0
    GPS_X = NumericProperty(0)
    GPS_Y = NumericProperty(0)
 
    @mainthread
    def on_location(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_lat = kwargs['lat']
        self.my_lon = kwargs['lon']
        self.pos_updater()

        return self.my_lat, self.my_lon

    def pos_updater(self):
        scaler = 100
        self.Y_value = scaler * 111320.0
        self.X_value = scaler * 40075000.0 * math.cos(self.my_lat)/360.0

        print("Delta:",self.Y_value, self.X_value)


    GPS_X += X_value + 100
    GPS_Y += Y_value
    
    def build(self):
        pass

Game().run()
```

main.kv

```
<Game>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 3
            Button:
                text: "higher"
                pos: (root.GPS_X, root.GPS_Y + root.height/2)
                on_release:
                    root.on_location()
        Label:
            id: time_id
            text: "test"
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'kivy.properties.NumericProperty' and 'int'
```

Comment: Try to update those values within a method.

Comment: I have set pos_updater to a @mainthread.  Still didn't work. How should I wirte it? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming ur are using a mapview:

in kivy file :

```
MapView:
    id: main_map
    size: root.width, root.height
    MapMarkerPopup: 
        source: 'pin.png'
        id: main_map_me
```

Now in ur main.py try this:

```
def on_location(self, *args, **kwargs):

   self.my_lat = kwargs['lat']
   self.my_lon = kwargs['lon']
   self.ids.main_map_me.lat = self.my_lat
   self.ids.main_map_me.lon = self.my_lon
```

its EASIER by id, use properties only when u cant use ids.(my opinion)

lets say ur Button has an id(btn)

in ur kivy file try this:

```
   Button:
       id: btn
```

in ur main.py try this:

```
self.ids.btn.pos[0] = self.width*0.5 # or whatever u need.....
self.ids.btn.pos[1] = self.height*   #..... whatever u need
```

And check the type of lat and lon if they are not strings cuz u are assuming that they are `NumericProperty` i think they are `StringProperty` if so just convert them and work with ur original code `stringproperty = float(my_Lat)`

And at last i dont know what u are trying to do with the scaler exactly but u must know that the screen position has nothing to do the position thats on the mapview.